# Issue with wayland and Nvidia gtx 1070ti with intel i11900k multi screen

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel, wayland

I have a problem with Ubuntu and I do not have enough knowledge to correct my issue.

First of all I want to stay on wayland not switch back to X11 because on X11  my screens works but  is laggy when I move windows

I was on Ubuntu 22.04.1 On wayland and after days of searching I was able to make this multi screen setup work with NVIDIA + intel. I have 6 screens, 4 on nivida gtx and 2 on the intel Motherboard. I remember I maded so many changes in grub like modeset with i915 and nvidia drm to make it work. I am not sure what fixed it.

So now I made last update of Ubuntu 22.10, I know it's switch to gnome 43, but I think its bug of config on Wayland because my state now is NVIDIA screens works good, and intel screen is detected on Xrander I can change pos or resolution but intel screen are blank,
they load but freezing on login screen. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04.1 back, but same issues.

If I boot with `nomodeset` system force me to be on x11 I don't know why, I disabled nvidia gdm rules to be able to boot on wayland with `modeset=0`.

If I boot with `nividia-drm.modeset=0`, Nvidia screens freeze, but intel screens work.

I do not know which dump you need to help me so be free to ask me some dumps.

Comment: You have a lot of stuff going on here I will address one issue. Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded. To be clear nomodeset tells your system not to use the drivers so yes you get X11. nomdoeset is a temp solution to get you to be able to use your system till you have the right video driver installed. It should not be used continually.

Comment: ty for your reply, yes I readed that so I boot by default with nividia-drm.modeset=1 and quiet splash so all screens is detected but intel screens stuck, I disable "quiet" temporaly and seems to be intel screens boot first after nvidia screen take relay and intel screens freeze and stay blank after login screen appear just on nvidia screens and intel screens stay freeze If I ctrl + shift+ f3 the tty console just open on 2 intel screens and nvidia screens freeze if I ctrl + shift +f2 gnome appear on nvidia screens and intel screens stuck again I dont know how to make work together

Comment: It might be difficult to succeed with Wayland (easier with Xorg (x11)). You have reasons to keep Wayland but be aware that there are problems with Wayland and nvidia graphics (and for that reason I use Xorg). Let us hope that there will be improved software soon.